# Why is the propriety of a scoring rule irrelevant for deterministic forecasts?

Tags: forecasting, scoring-rules

By deterministic forecasts Jolliffe (2008) has in mind forecasts to which no representation of uncertainty is attached.

Jolliffe (2008) p26 provides a standard explanation of proper scoring rules, similar to that provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Proper_scoring_rules). He then writes:

> Propriety is, however, irrelevant for deterministic forecasts, as the
>   definition involves an expectation over the forecaster’s believed
>   probability distribution. It is difficult to conceive of a situation
>   where a forecaster’s genuine belief is deterministic. If a
>   deterministic forecast is issued, it is usually because the
>   forecaster’s probabilistic belief has been converted into a
>   deterministic statement using some ‘directive’ [...].
>   However, for the moment, let us suppose that a forecaster is using his
>   or her genuine belief when issuing a deterministic forecast. Then the
>   forecaster is certain that the forecast will be correct, and knows
>   that the best possible value of the score will be achieved, regardless
>   of what score is used. Hence, there is no incentive to hedge, and all
>   scores are proper for deterministic forecasts.

I am unsure of what Jolliffe (2008) means. I think critical part of the passage is the bit that refers to "the definition involves an expectation over the forecaster’s believed probability distribution". I am unsure what this means, and how it follows from this that the propriety of a scoring rule is irrelevant for deterministic forecasts.

Jolliffe, I. T. (2008). The impenetrable hedge: A note on propriety, equitability and consistency. *Meteorological Applications*, *15*, 25-30.
Chicago

Comment: [Here is a link](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/met.60)  (for now at least open access)

Comment: Didn't read the paper (so far), but this sound as a subjective bayes argument. If the forecaster is subjectively sure of the forecast, he doesn't feel the need for hedging, but still his consumers might feel that need.  I might be subjectively sure that my house will not burn, but I will still buy insurance ...